# Ruby On Rails Application.html.haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, haml, hyperlink

I am using Ruby On Rails 2.3.5 with haml version 2.2.21 (in my environment.rb file) And all the links I generate in views (using haml) adds the link itself at the end.

Ex :

```
%li 
    =link_to 'sign up', {:controller=> 'users' , :action=> 'signup'}
```

Displays 
        sign up(users/signup)

Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just be able to do:

```
=link_to 'Sign Up', user_registration_path
```

For future reference, you can run the command

```
rake routes
```

To get a list of all the named routes in your application:

```
$ rake routes
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
  destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
         user_password PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
     user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)                                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
     user_registration DELETE /users(.:format)                                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
```

The route name is listed in the leftmost column.  You can then append '_path' to any of those to access that path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am doing exactly what you are saying and the result ius as descripbed. It always displays the signup(users/signup)

Comment: Can you post your code (with a bit more of context), and the rendered HTML?